# closing an sqlite database - android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

There's a `close` method provided by the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and also a `close` method provided by the writable database instance of the `SQLiteDatabase` passed in the `onOpen` and `onCreate` method when extending the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

Since we don't explicitly open the database ourselves and rely on the framework, I'm confused which `close()` method should I invoke in order to properly close the database when all my transactions have been done.